# Saturn is "singing" to Enceladus?

Tags: saturn, cassini, enceladus

[This](https://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/us_5b456bd8e4b048036ea39dfd) article claims Cassini, during its final few weeks around Saturn, detected plasma waves that were directed at Enceladus.

How do we know these detected plasma waves were "directed" at Enceladus? Or are they just plasma Cassini encountered, and Enceladus happened to be on the other side of the Saturn Enceladus line?

Comment: The Huffington Post is not the ideal source for news about planetary science. Take a look at the question [What is the nature of a “flux tube” between Saturn and Enceladus, and what does “L‐shell=4” mean?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28332/12102) and the answer(s) there to get a better idea of what is (or in this case, *isn't*) happening.

Comment: @uhoh that might well be a duplicate for this question, though I didn't have the search terms to find it. Edit, yup, that question has the same EM profile huffpost posted in their "song". Feel free to post a dupe, to direct others to the real science

Comment: I'm not an astrophysicist, but I do consider myself a scientist,, so huffpost articles lead me to want to verify their claims, either in more searches or on here. The linked article didn't provide many keywords to search, so i asked here

Comment: I know the feeling. I've asked several questions in various SE sites that call into question statements in the popular press. There is related information in the Q and A I've linked to above, but I am not sure why the "singing" can be heard *only along the field lines that happen to geometrically intercept Enceladus*. One way is to dupe this but another way might be to slightly modify this question and ask why only those field lines. The other answer there may touch on it indirectly, but I don't think it's fully explained there. You could add a link to that answer in the question here.